# How to close a form on a new thread from a form which is in another thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to figure this out for the past day or so.

I have a program which has Form1, and a button that spawns Form2 in a new thread.

I also have another button on Form1 that should close Form2, but since Form2 is in another thread, I cannot touch that object directly.

I could do `t.Abort()` but that throws an exception.

How can I gracefully touch the other thread? Do stuff to it?

For example, how do I close the form from within Form1?

I've searched google for "how to close a form from within another thread" and found several links hinting at Invoke and Delegate, but after trying some things, I obviously can't figure out how to use it properly.

Can anyone help me to understand how it would apply to the code I have, so that I can understand how they can be used? in which context, etc?

I've uploaded the project to github for your convenience: https://github.com/powercat/WindowsFormsApplication7/archive/master.zip

--

Code:

[Form1.cs]

```
    public void FormThread()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FormThread));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Need to close Form2 from here.

    }
```

[Form2.cs]

has the other form code.

Comment: Don't use multilpe UI threads.  Just don't.  It will make your life hell, and the winforms framework just isn't really built to support it.  Use a single UI thread for your program.

Comment: You should just paste the code you're trying in your post. I'm not going to open that file up on my computer.

Comment: I cannot access GitHub from my place of work.  Just paste the code where you create and start the thread.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some code. But if I start another UI window, the previous one is "frozen", that is why I was using the other thread. Reed Copsey is suggesting BackGroundWorkers, is that the right way to do this?

Comment: @PowerCat If you're blocking your UI thread to do non-UI work then that's a problem.  You fix it by doing the non-UI work in a non-UI thread, not by creating two UI threads and blocking one form instead of another.

Answer (score 3):

In general, having two threads for two forms is not a good idea.  It's almost always a better idea to have all of your forms on the main, UI thread, and move your logic and work onto background threads instead.

That being said, if the Form is being run in the separate thread, you should be able to use `BeginInvoke` to close it:

```
 otherForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => otherForm.Close()));
```

---

Edit:

In your case, you'd need to save the instance:

```
Form2 otherForm;
public void FormThread()
{       
    otherForm = new Form2();
    Application.Run(otherForm);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FormThread));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); // THIS IS REQUIRED!
    t.Start();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Need to close Form2 from here.
    if (otherForm != null)
    {
       otherForm.BeginInvoke(new Action( () => otherForm.Close() ));
       otherForm = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I keep seeing "otherForm" but that's one of the part I don't understand. What is "otherForm"? How does it fit with the code? I will look into background threads.

Comment: The "BeginInvoke" method doesn't appear on the intellisense when I type Form2. This BeginInvoke is what I have seen on other answers, but was never able to implement it in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Would you be so kind as to point out which line, in which file I would add that line? And how would I made button2_Click execute that command, since I can't add it in that event?

Comment: @PowerCat You'd need to save the `new Form2()` instance somewhere - and have access to it.

Comment: @PowerCat Added code for you - note the STA thread call, too (you'll need that)